# Best Books to learn Proof-Based Linear Algebra and Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, book-recommendation

So I'm in a really serious problem. It's my first year at university and I'm doing a CS major. The math is already getting serious and I'm lost, really lost. It's all about matrices so far and the thing is I really can't do the proofs (of determinants). High school(A-level) was math was pie and it didn't even involve any proofs and that's where I'm lacking now and I'm stressed out. I don't know where to start.
So I went online and looked at all the books that have been listed around and  here are some I found:
Linear Algebra Done Right - Axler
Intro. to Linear algebra - Gilbert Strang
Linear Algebra - Hoffman and Kunze

These are some, but I'm not sure where to start. I need a book which will teach me some basic proofs and how to think to solve these proofs. So anyone could help me  out, where to start?

Comment: MO is intended for topics at the graduate school level and above.

Comment: Mathstackexchange might get you a good answer.

Comment: I wouldn't use Hoffman and Kunze unless you're already acquainted with mathematical proofs. Besides, it goes beyond just matrices and vector spaces and I would almost consider it a book in abstract algebra.

Comment: Strange is more computationally oriented although it does have proofs. Intended to some extent for engineers. You can find a very nice set of his videos teaching his course at MIT at their OCW site. Axler is more proof oriented, although starting at a somewhat elementary level. If you want to ever do rigorous math, especially pertaining to LA, Axler is a good place to expend some effort.

Answer (score 1):

There is a HUGE amount of Linear Algebra books. Let me point out just two:

- Noble, Daniel, Applied Linear Algebra. Prentice Hall.
- Lancaster, Tismenetsky, The Theory of Matrices. Academic Press.

I would suggest the first one for a beginner and later on you can take a look at the second one. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Elementary Linear Algebra by Larson.  There are basic proofs and also exercises called "guided proofs" that help with initial intuition and explain why you are doing the steps.  There are lots and lots of problems to solve but the proofs are there as well and they are not of high mathematics.  Axler is good too but requires a bit more foundationally.

Comment: $174,66!! http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Linear-Algebra-Ron-Larson/dp/1133110878  Are you kidding me? Is the world getting crazy or what?

Comment: I definitely didn't pay that much!  And I would say if that is the going rate, then don't go that route.  I payed 3 years ago about $50 for a used copy.

Comment: Larson doesn't seem to have enough proofs to serve as an introduction to the latter. I'd rather get some slow-paced introduction tailored for pure mathematicians in the OP's place.

Comment: I know it's not an introductory book, but Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra is free in the internet now....